# Static class in Swift

Tags: java, swift, react-native

I'v implemented a static TimeMonitor class in Java that look like this:

```
    public class SomeClass {
        private static ArrayList<String> _myList = new ArrayList<>();

        public static void add(String str) {
            _myList.add(str);
        }

        public static int getCount() {
            return _myList.length;
        }
    }
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
SomeClass.add("my string")
```

so when I'll call

```
int count = SomeClass.getCount()
```

The value of `count` will be `1`

I do I implement the equivalent code in Swift 3?

I've found this question: 
[How can I create a static class in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992430/how-can-i-create-a-static-class-in-swift), but I can't find a reference to an example that shows not only static methods but also saving static data as demonstrated in the Java example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41560949/2303865

Answer (score 1):

Immediately off the top of my head, maybe something like...

```
public class SomeClass {
    internal static var myList: [String] = []

    public static var count: Int {
        return myList.count
    }

    public static func add(_ str: String) {
        myList.append(str)
    }
}
```

Then you could use it something like..

```
SomeClass.add("Hello")
let count = SomeClass.count
```

Equally, you could use a `struct`, since you can't really override anything, for example...

```
public struct SomeClass {
    internal static var myList: [String] = []

    public static var count: Int {
        return myList.count
    }

    public static func add(_ str: String) {
        myList.append(str)
    }
}
```